# Where is XMonad state saved

Tags: workspace, xmonad

I have a setup with 3 monitors. Lately I have decreased the selectable workspaces in my xmonad config to three (1,2 and 3) however xmonad has somehow remembered my previous layout and still displays workspace 5 on one of the monitors on statup, so I always need to explicitly switch. 
Where is the persistent state saved and how can I reset it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it: file `.xmonad/xmonad.state`

Comment: You're probably running into this error: https://github.com/xmonad/xmonad/issues/86 might be worth updating your XMonad